# why does Guice create a new instance for my singleton?

Tags: java, singleton, guice

I have this guice code

```
public class MainModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
  bind(GlobalSettings.class).toProvider(GlobalSettingsProvider.class).in(Singleton.class);
}
```

and

```
public class GlobalSettingsProvider implements Provider<GlobalSettings> {

    @Override
    public GlobalSettings get() {

        GlobalSettings globalSettings = new GlobalSettings();
        globalSettings.isDummyRun = Boolean.parseBoolean(System.getProperty("isDummyRun", "false"));
        globalSettings.inputFlavor = System.getProperty("input_flavor", "none");
    }
}
```

and

```
public class A(){

    public A() {
        this.injector = Guice.createInjector(new MainModule());
injector.getInstance(IHttpClientReRunWrapper.class);
        globalSettings = injector.getInstance(GlobalSettings.class);

    resultsComparerRunner1 = injector.getInstance(ResultsComparerRunner.class);
    resultsComparerRunner2 = injector.getInstance(ResultsComparerRunner.class);
    resultsComparerRunner3 = injector.getInstance(ResultsComparerRunner.class);
  }
}
```

and

```
public class ResultsComparerRunner(){

public class ResultsComparerRunner(){
initStaticFromInjector();
}

    private void initStaticFromInjector() {
        routingResponseShortRepository = injector.getInstance(IRoutingResponseShortRepository.class);
        globalSettings = injector.getInstance(GlobalSettings.class); //verify only one injector per run
    }
```

why do I see `globalSettings` in instance of `A` and in instance of  `ResultsComparerRunner` are different?

I wanted it to be singelton

Answer (score 6):

I was curious about the behavior of provider binding plus singleton, so I created a test-[gist](https://gist.github.com/jangalinski/1bdc0cf1ec98ec9a6c64) based on your code:

```
 @Test
 public void execute() {
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new AbstractModule() {
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            bind(GlobalSettings.class).toProvider(GlobalSettingsProvider.class).in(Singleton.class);
        }
    });

    GlobalSettings g1 = injector.getInstance(GlobalSettings.class);
    GlobalSettings g2 = injector.getInstance(GlobalSettings.class);

    assertThat(g1).isSameAs(g2);
}
```

Result: green. Meaning that your module setup is working, your problem must lie somewhere else. How do you pass the injector to the ResultsComparerRunner? Is this really the injector containing the singleton definition?

Answer (score 2):

My problem was that I called

`injector = Guice.createInjector(new MainModule());`

twice in two different places-

which created two singletons.